# Write a php socket which refresh html content non-stop

Tags: php, sockets

I really would like to try using php sockets but unfortunately i am still not near doing it. However I would like to build a server side which will select some stuff from the database a write a html to the user page without user needs to do anything, just the information to pops up in front of him.

Is this possible ?

I tried different demoes and I don't understand why my socket only works on port 80, should I change the port, and how to do that ?

If someone have a very simple and short code for the server and for the html to post, just the basic stuff I should be able to do the rest.

Thanks!

Comment: "Is this possible ?" **Yes!** :)

Comment: @nerfair i wonder if it possible. Please give some resource that i can think it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An php script cant modify html that already sent to browser. But you can request data using ajax.

Want to learn socket programming using php? See [Php socket](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/418814/Socket-Programming-in-PHP) tutorial

Comment: that actually worked perfect and i Think i got the point :-),but

how can i make this running all the time so when i open client.php it wont crash that the server port is busy. And how can i modify some data while i am watching client.php ?

Comment: A server shouldn't run multiple instance. Just put some logic that it will handle many connection. Also clear the idea what you tried to do with.

Comment: Well i for example i want to have a text editor (with some text) in the middle of the web page. This text editor can be edited by other users at all the time, so i want when i have opened it to see the changes without needing to refresh the page

Comment: That all you need is all about ajax. php socket is not designed to do it. @Izopi4a

Comment: i can easily make it with ajax requests will be much more easier for me, but isn't It better socket style ?
Node js is also an option :-)

Comment: @Izopi4a I do not know node.js, but you should take what works for you.